# Django: Error when running python manage.py collectstatic - SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: python, reactjs, django, deployment

I'm preparing to deploy a Django application with a React frontend to Heroku. When I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, I receive the following **error**:

`raise SuspiciousFileOperation(django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/Users/x/Desktop/x/_code/app/static/media/SourceCodePro-Light.77e36241fe57a40a332a.otf) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/x/Desktop/x/_code/app/staticfiles)`

I've followed the Django documentation on configuring `django.contrib.staticfiles` for deployment. The relevant settings in **settings.py**:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = False

...

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

As I understand it, the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting directs Django where to look for additional static files to collect in the `STATIC_ROOT`. And the error I'm receiving appears to be because the joined path is not contained within the base path.

The problem is that, if this is the case, I don't understand why the base path component does not refer to `BASE_DIR`, i.e. `/Users/x/Desktop/x/_code/app/`.

I've tried every permutation of adding/removing slashes in every path in the relevant settings, as well as setting `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR`. Actually, no matter what I change `STATIC_ROOT` to, I receive the same error and the `/Users/x/Desktop/x/_code/app/staticfiles` folder is still generated. This leads me to believe that my setting is being overriden somewhere.

Thank you in advance for any solutions provided.